# How Curly Brackets work in Boost::extension, how to make such macros on my own?

Tags: c++, boost, macros, brackets, boost-extension

I look at how we use Boost::Extension `BOOST_EXTENSION_TYPE_MAP_FUNCTION` macro.

For example like [this](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/trunk/CloudServer/src/default-services/file_service/file_service.cpp?r=1394):

```
BOOST_EXTENSION_TYPE_MAP_FUNCTION
{
    std::map<std::string, boost::extensions::factory<service> > &factories(types.get());
    factories["file_service"].set<file_service>();
}
```

`BOOST_EXTENSION_TYPE_MAP_FUNCTION` macro is defined in [extension.hpp](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/branches/v0.4/CloudServerPrototype/3rdparty/header-only/boost/extension/extension.hpp?r=1294).

I wonder how this macro understands what is in Curly Brackets and how for example expand this macro to something that would cout anything like "Hello extended macro"?

Comment: the macro doesn't understand anything(?) it is simply replaced - so in effect (if you ignore the calling convention stuff) becomes `void boost_extension_exported_type_map_function(boost::extensions::type_map& types)` (I've left out the `extern "C"` bit too), i.e. a function...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me put my comment into an answer...

A macro is an instruction to the compiler (I use the collective term here) to substitute at that location the symbols defined as that macro, for example

```
#define FOO 1

int val = FOO; // at this point, FOO is replaced with 1
```

(p.s. please don't do this in C++)

Now, what is happening in your case is that there is a set of symbols (the signature of a function) defined as a macro, so all that happens is the compiler will substitute the macro with the symbols, and the end result would look (roughly) like this:

```
void boost_extension_exported_type_map_function(boost::extensions::type_map& types)
{
    std::map<std::string, boost::extensions::factory<service> > &factories(types.get());
    factories["file_service"].set<file_service>();
}
```

Which as you can see is a simple function. You can do this too (but don't unless you have a very good reason)

```
#define BOB void foo(std::string const& bar)

BOB
{
  std::cout << "HEllo: " << bar << std::endl;
}
```

It simply allows a user to define their own implementation for that function... presumably somewhere else - it takes the address of that function and uses it via a pointer...